# Error: <line> attribute y1: Expected length, "{{i.y}}" .Error is shown in chrome console but svg is working fine

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, svg

I am trying to pass dynamic value to svg using angular . functionality is working properly but getting error in console.

```
<g  class="tick" transform="translate({{getGraphY($index)}},0)" style="opacity: 1;">
    <line y1="-20"y2="390" x2="0" style="stroke:lightgrey;stroke-width:10" ></line>-->
    <text dy=".71em" y="-15" x="-35.625"  style="text-anchor: middle;">{{getGraphNameDay(i.dow)}}</text>
    <text dy=".71em" y="-0" x="-35.625" style="text-anchor:middle;">{{getGraphDay(i.date)}}</text>
    <text dy=".71em" y="280" x="-35.625" style="text-anchor:middle;">{{i.maxorders}}</text>
</g>
```

Angular 1.4 code

```
$scope.getGraphY=function(y){
  var x=[];
  for (i = 72.25;i <= 580; i = i + 72.25) {
    x.push(i);
  }
  return x[y];
}
```

[Below Error in Chrome Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh6od.jpg)

Comment: Hi there! Tip: it is always best to post error messages as text, as it is more accessible that way.

Comment: try translate({{getGraphY($index)+',0'}})

Comment: Missing a space here: y1="-20"y2="390" between " and y